Sequence and class diagrams for use case "Browse"
I was told to add a sequence and class diagram for the use case "Browse" in my project report, which is supposed to be: <User should be able to browse the homepage, about us page, and blog page content>
is this even possible? or is there better diagrams for this?
Keep in mind my project has no back end.
I completely glossed over it in my report and got told it was wrong.

One could argue that browse is not a use-case except if your project is a new browser. In your case, actors are interested in content, and browsing is only a mean to achieve this goal/use-case. But I understand that you did not chose, so let's go on.
It is perfectly possible to have a sequence diagram describing this "use case". For example having a user and the system as lifelines, the user sending a message "get homepage" and the system replies with the home page, etc.
You can subdivide further the system into parts, like a web interface and the blogging content, or a model, views with their controler (example: here) and imagine how these objects interact to provide the information to the user. Each of these lifeline would correspond to an instance of a class, and you then just show theses classes and their relationship in a class diagram.
In the end however, your requirement  narrative seems to describe a user interface and the navigation possibilities rather than a real use-case. UML is not the best choice for user-interface design, and the UML founders even warned against it. Other techniques like wire framing and similar techniques are more suitable for this purpose.

Completely agree with uml not being the best choice for UI design, but what can i do haha.
i understand how to do the sequence now, but don't really get the class diag part. Can i get an example somewhere?

If you consider the MVC example,  here you'll find a classical MVC example with both the class-diagram and the sequence diagram.  By analogy with your sequence diagram, you'll be able to adapt it to your needs.  Just keep in mind that sequence is about behavior/dynamics whereas class is about static structure
